# Posting Firebases's thirdpartyuserdata object to the server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm using Firebase and the SimpleLogin to allow users to login via Google, Twitter etc.

I'd like to use some of the `thirdpartyuserdata` object to create a user profile for my application which runs on Node.

Currently I'm posting this data to the server so that I can add to it and create the profile object, but I wondered if there's a better way of doing this - is there something I can call server side to get this `thirdpartyuserdata` without having to post it from the client?

Comment: Are you saying that you do a AJAX post to store the data in another database? If you provided some code that would make things a bit easier to help :)

Comment: @David Yes, I post the data received on the client to my node server, where the object is embellished with other properties before saving it into my Firebase ref. Ideally I'd like to get hold of that third party data server side so it's a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Start by considering that your "server" is actually just another consumer of Firebase data. Since FirebaseSimpleLogin is simply a token generator with some fancy tools for doing OAuth, and because this happens completely client-side, there is nothing to consume about this.

If you want to consume the data at the server, you will either need to POST it, as you have done, or use Firebase to transfer the information. You'll find that a [queue approach](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue) can save you a large amount of code, as this allows you to use Firebase as the API, and avoid creating RESTful services in Node, and all the baggage that comes with that.

The idea of a queue is simply that you push data into Firebase at one client and read it out (and probably delete it) at the intended recipient (in this case your node worker).