# Is Firebase's built-in authentication able to be used on a 3rd party server?

Tags: authentication, backend, firebase-authentication

I'm looking to create a game server backend for a game I'm creating. We're currently using Firebase for handling of data and ads, and Firebase has built in authentication. Is it possible to have a user log into our app via Firebase's auth system, then confirm the user's authentication when they connect to the game server to ensure it's who they say they are?

Basically, after someone logs into our firebase, can we use that authentication information for a separate server, and what protocol/method would need to be used (if there's a specific one)

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740884/posting-firebasess-thirdpartyuserdata-object-to-the-server You need to use the firebase-queue :)

Comment: Since you are using a custom backend server, you should take a look Info the Admin SDK/Admin Auth API https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/ The token the client SDK issues confirm to the Openidconnect spec, the Admin SDK provides you the capability to verify tokens https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
Hth

Answer (score 10):

I've figured out the two steps you need to get the information required to auth, one clientside and one serverside. Note: the following examples are for the Java apis, but you can use any of firebase's equivalents.

**Clientside**: In the Firebase-Auth package, there's the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-constructor-summary) object. This contains information about their auth state, unique details, etc. There is a method here called getToken(), which will grab your token for the current authentication. Once you have this, you want to send it to the server when you need to auth.

**Serverside**: On the server, there's a [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/serverreference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth) object. Once you get the token from the client, you can use verifyIdToken(), which will confirm this is a valid token and give you the details about the user when you get the result. I suggest cross-checking the UUID against one a client sends, to just confirm someone didn't get their hands on a token and send a random ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As this keeps getting upvotes, I just wanted to warn you: I wrote this when I was 15. Please do not take security advice from 15 year old me. Definitely do further research than this.